# Combinatorics with Linear Algebra, solution of a game.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Alice and Bob play the following game.
A blank $2010$$\times$$2010$ array is taken. Alice starts the game by writing a real number in any one of the squares of the array. Then Bob writes a real number in any blank square of the array. The game is continued till all the squares are filled with numbers. Alice wins the game if the determinant of the resulting matrix is non-zero and Bob wins the game if the determinant of the resulting matrix is zero. Show that Bob can always win the game.

Now see, we have to just prove that the determinant of a $2010$$\times$$2010$ matrix with real entries is always zero. Let Alice put the real number $x$ in ($i$,$j$)th cell. Now I'm stucked. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Putnam 2008-A2 See http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2008s.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a matrix has zero determinant iff its rows are not linearly independent. So, Bob could just replicate Alice's numbers (or a multiple of them) on the upper or lower row. If she then *invades* that row, he can write on the row she was previously writing on. Since the number of rows is even, Bob will always have the "last word on it".

The same can be done with columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try experimenting with the game yourself on a smaller $2 \times 2$ matrix, and try to come up with your own winning strategy as Bob. Then try the same strategy on a $4 \times 4$ matrix.